# Trying to create jump function but player barely jumps

Tags: game-physics

Hi I am using pygame to attempt to make a platformer however something is making the player suddenly go down when it jumps, so the player makes a small jump and falls straight down afterwards.
Here is the code that is responsible for the jumping:

```
def update(self):
    self.speedx = 0
    self.speedy = 0
    self.gravity = 3
    self.onGround = True

    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if self.rect.y <= HEIGHT - 50:
        self.speedy += self.gravity
        self.onGround = False
    if self.rect.y >= HEIGHT - 50:
        self.speedy = 0
        self.onGround = True

    if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.speedx = -5
    if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.speedx = 5
    if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.jump()
    self.rect.x += self.speedx
    self.rect.y += self.speedy

def jump(self):
    if self.onGround == False:

        return
    self.speedy = -10
```

Comment: The issue might be that the update loop is running much faster than you realize. It takes only four iterations for the player to start moving downwards.

Comment: Looks like gravity hurts. Make the game a little floatier so your player can move more easily.

Comment: As said by Starman, seems to be an unbalance between how much the player goes up and how much it is brought down. With 30fps, the player landed in about 0.2 seconds. Maybe to fast to notice.
My advice is to put self.speedy = -15 and self.gravity = 1.5
If things get better, you have found the problem!

Comment: It works however the player cannot be seen going upwards, so the player basically teleports.

Comment: If you have a fast refresh rate and a big enough sprite, it should not be so bad (I have done the same not long ago, with the same parameters). Of course, if the sprite is just few pixel tall, 15 pixel is quite a jump.
Otherwise, you have to change the jump algorithm.
If you post the entire code I can try to run it and see what happens.